# How to get POST data in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I send POST data like this:

```
{
  "email": "oli@mail.ru"
}
```

Or like form-data: key => value

I validate email field:

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email|string',
        ]);
```

It fails, cause `$request` is not contain email field.

If to do this:

```
   dd($request->all());
```

It gives me empty array `[]`,

How to get POST field email?

Comment: please post your controller method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your request includes the header `Content-Type: application/json`.